# Avoid Safari iOS navigation bar overlap with 100vh elements?

Tags: html, ios, css

I've stumbled upon this problem a couple of times, but I can't really remember how to work around it.

I have an element with `height:100vh` applied to it. The element is the first element in the view when visiting the page, so the visitor should see the element cover the whole screen without it cropping. When trying this out on Safari iOS (maybe Chrome too, I haven't checked), the viewport is covered by the "navigation bar" at the bottom until you begin to scroll.

One important thing about the element is that it should have borders, so this issue becomes more critical than usual as the border on the bottom should not be cropped out.

As the example is a bit hard to show on JSFiddle or similar, as the window dimensions has to be native, I've made this demo instead:
http://www.tobiasgerhardsson.com/ios_bug

The code I've set up for the demo is the following:

**CSS**

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    width:100%;
    border:3px solid red;
}

.height-100vh {
    height:calc(100vh);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <section class="height-100vh">This is it</section>
   <section>...</section>
   <section>...</section>
</body>
```

Here's an image showing the issue:
[image: Image showing the navigation bar covering issue in Safari iOS]

How do I work around this issue with the navigation bar covering the content? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I guess a year without a proper reply tells the story quite well...

Comment: Yes, but nowadays I just use `height: 100%` on all the parent containers for, in this example, the hero. Including `body` and `html`. And then also on the hero container itself. But that creates some problems with the flow of the layout in some occurences.

Comment: I solved it by implementing a react hook observing the window.innerWidth/Height and writing in redux on resize. My Components‘ state can always hook in and check for innerHeight changes.